# I2C response to "Ghost Address" 0x5F

Tags: i2c

I recently bought a [ZS-042 RTC module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Arduino-DS3231-ZS042-AT24C32-IIC-Module-Precision-RTC-Real-time-Clock-Memory-/401093092939) which communicates using the I2C protocol. The module includes a [DS3231 (RTC)](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) and an [AT24C32 (4k EEPROM)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc0336.pdf).

The ZS-042 module has no datasheet, but the Ebay listing (linked above) shows how the DS3231 and AT24C32 are assembled on to the module (ZS-042 is NOT an IC).

When I bought it, I had no idea what the I2C addresses where for the device, so I ran a quick scan and addresses 0x57, 0x5F and 0x68 acknowledged.

I am a little bit confused because the module only includes two I2C devices, but I am getting the ACK from three. I researched and the I2C addresses 0x57 and 0x68 correspond to the DS3131 and AT24C32 respectively, but I couldn't find a single device with the 0x5F address.

I tried running the scan with the module disconnected, and all three addresses disappeared.  When reconnected, all three addresses reappeared. To make matters worse, when I send a byte to the ghost device, the device ACKs!

I can physically see only two ICs soldered to the ZS-042.

**Any ideas which device is responding to I2C address 0x5F?**

P.S.
I am using an Arduino UNO with a custom library in order to run the I2C lines under 3.3V (not the standard 5V) from any pair of digital pins. I wrote the library myself using the I2C protocol guidelines and I have thoroughly tested it on EEPROM. This is a link to the library files:

https://github.com/JuaFMaldonado/I2C-Trough-Digital

I am using this simple sketch to scan for devices:

```
#include <I2CDigital.h>

#define WRITE 0b00000000
#define READ 0b00000001

I2CDigital I2C(12,11);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for(int i=16;i<120;i++){
    if(I2C.startCom((byte)i,WRITE)){
      Serial.print("Device detected at address: ");
      Serial.println(i);
      if(I2C.sendByte(0b00000000)){
        Serial.println("Byte sent successfully");
      }
      I2C.stopCom();
      delayMicroseconds(5);
    }
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT suggested by @ChrisStratton:

To be able to use any pair of digital pins for I2C communication, the pins are only allowed to run in `pinMode(pin,INPUT)` (for logic high) or `pinMode(pin,OUTPUT)` and `digitalWrite(pin,LOW)` (for logic low). The lines can then be connected to any desired pull up voltage (as long as it is still recognised by the device as logic high).

In my particular case they are connected to the 3.3V regulator on the Arduino through 4.7k resistors.

EDIT suggested by @ElliotAlderson:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flChyC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT sugested by @Janka

DS3131

[image: DS3131]

AT24C32

[image: AT24C32]

Comment: You should document the electrical solution which allows you to operate 3v3 I2C via these GPIO pins (but apparently not via the standard ones?).   What value are your I2C pullup resistors?  If you are using some sort of level translator, what value are the pullups on each bus side?

Comment: Please show us a schematic of your circuit, and provide links to the datasheets of the two I2C devices.

Comment: No datasheet? No other device on bus?

Comment: @ChrisStratton edit made.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson edit made.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I do have a 24LC64 EEPROM on the bus, but I have tested the ZS-042 module without the 24LC64 on the bus and the problem persists. There is no address conflict as the 24LC64 has address 0X50. With only the ZS-042 connected to the bus, I am detecting 3 devices (When there are only two advertised and soldered to the module). Also, I can't find any device with address 0X5F online.

Comment: 0x5F is most likely a *mirrored* address of 0x57 of the AT24C32. The datasheet denies it, but who knows what knock-off you have there on the board. Please send photos of the chip.

Comment: Ok, so check for signal integrity. It's possible that you have bad pullups or something and so 57 and 5f look the same to the slave.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I changed the pullups to 1K (total overkill) and the issue persists.

Comment: It's not clear why you think you have different voltage allowances on random digital pins than on the hardware I2C pins; I2C is an *open-collector* (or in this case, open-drain) bus.  If properly implemented positive signals should be being provided only by the pull-up resistors, irrespective of MCU supply voltage, even if you use the hardware I2C.

Comment: @JPhysicsFM ok, if you saw the image on scope anf everything is fine, then I don't know. But! I think i would not care much..

Comment: Trying this with the hardware I2C or someone else's implementation would help rule out a subtle bug in the logic or especially timing of yours, which might cause aliasing under some situations.

Comment: @Janka edit made. I have never heard of that. Please develop it as an answer explaining as much as you can why it happens and what happens if I read/write to the mirrored address. You will most likely get marked as the most useful answer and it could help people that have the same issue in the future identify it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am not 100% about this, but I think the Arduino UNO has the hardware I2C pins (A4 and A5) hardwired to 5V pull up resistors. The module is rated for 3.3V, as it has a 3.3V battery backup that could cause serious issues if supplied with 5V. I am pretty sure connecting external 3.3V pull up resistors to the already pulled up 5V lines could cause all sorts of issues and even hardware damage (reverse polarity on the voltage regulator). Any digital (or even analog) pin can be used with the software, as long as it's not pulled up to 5V.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum It's not a serious issue, but it's good to understand why the hardware is reacting the way it is. It can help us fix or even exploit the issue for our advantage. I don't have a scope, but 1K pull up resistors should be overkill considering the standard is 4.7K for short distances.

Comment: 1k should be fine, agreed. But it may be about something else. Did you search addresses without the RTC board?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Yes

Comment: Did you slow down the clock? Oh, by the way, why don't you search 0 to 127?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum The clock was already on the slow side for I2C, although it could have been a good debugging method. addresses 0-15 are reserved I2C commands.

Comment: @JPhysicsFM You are mistaken.  **The Arduino UNO _DOES NOT_ have I2C pull-up resistors** on board.  So you are free to use your own to an appropriate supply rail.  Having them built in would be an undesireable complication, not only for what you are doing, but because the I2C pins are also usable as analog inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original AT24C32 (and friends) say **ATMEL** in the beginning of the first line of the marking, not ATMLH (or anything else).

The chip on your board is a knock-off of the original AT24C32. It may do **anything**. Please refer to the datasheet of that ATMLH24C32 chip, if you can find it. I suspect this thing has an incomplete address decoder to make it possible to pass for two different chips, the AT24C32 and some other original at address 0x5f.

Comment: You nailed it! To test it I pulled down A2 from the AT24C32. Originally I was getting address 0b01010111 with mirror address 0b01011111. When I pulled down A2 I got address 0b01010011 with mirror address 0b01011011. Both the original and the mirror have 0 and 1 accordingly for bit 4, no matter what the next three bits (A2,A1,A0) are! Thank you

Comment: Wild guess: I think this is because these chips are used as parameter storage for car ECUs. Parts manufacturers as Bosch may have tried to impede chip tuning by ordering "special" chips from Atmel et al with different addresses, so you couldn't simply exchange the chip. And the knock-off market reacted to this.